# How to automatically disable abbrev-mode when entering math environment?

Tags: latex, abbrev

I use abbrev-mode mostly for usual text in LaTeX. How can I automatically disable it when entering math environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your abbrevs are mode-specific (e.g., inserted via <kbd>C-x a l</kbd> or <kbd>C-x a i l</kbd>), then you can simply set the `enable-function` property of `latex-mode-abbrev-table`, as in

```lisp
(abbrev-table-put latex-mode-abbrev-table :enable-function (lambda () (not (texmathp))))
```

Now mode-specific abbrevs won’t expand inside of math delimiters.  You should of course arrange for the above code to be evaluated only after latex.el and abbrev.el have been loaded.

**Edit:**  If you’re using global abbrevs, you can do something similar with `global-abbrev-table` instead of `latex-mode-abbrev-table`, but you should also for example check if the buffer’s mode is (derived from) `latex-mode`.